# Where should the contents of /sys/kernel/kheaders.tar.xz be installed?

Tags: linux, include-path

Recent Linux kernels can be built with a copy of the kernel headers included -- these are available in a pseudo file at `/sys/kernel/kheaders.tar.xz`.  This unpacks to a tree with `arch` and `include`.  `include` has about 30 subdirectories, including `linux`, and `arch` leads to a tree of what looks like related architecture files.

Is there a single place that the contents can be unpacked so that the C compiler can access the headers at the expected places?  (Including intra-header inclusion, *e.g.*, `<linux/gpio/consumer.h>` includes `<linux/bug.h>`, which includes `<asm/bug.h>`.)

I tried just unpacking everything into `/usr/include`, which sort-of kind-of works, but the `arch` stuff is not at all in the right place.  Plus, unpacking over an existing `/usr/include` feels sloppy -- stuff might get clobbered, and you'll have a mess the next time you upgrade the kernel.

Is there a Best Practices that kernel developers use for this?